# Google Map SDK , iOS and -ObjC issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode7

I'm developing an app, i was using mapKit to handle my maps, but now I'm switching to GoogleMap, but i'm having a lot of issues and i don't know how to fix this...

Framework: GoogleMapsM4B.framework /GoogleMaps.bundle
Flag: -ObjC
Xcode 7
Swift

Any idea?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: you are using swift or Objective C ?

Comment: Im using Swift for everything

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me answer this.

I did a few errors with this thing, i was including extras "parse frameworks", and i forgot some parts of the Parse Documentation:

> If you're using the -ObjC linker flag required by some third-party
>   libraries, add these as well:
>
> Accounts.framework
>
> Social.framework

Google Map needs -ObjC flag

The extra frameworks that i was including along with Parse:

> ParseFacebookUtils.framework
>
> ParseUI.framework
>
> ParseCrashReporting.framework

Now i removed the extras frameworks and everything is working!

Thanks!